# Tinymce is only loading once within jquery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

im reading a html file using jquery and grabbing a content in a div and wrap them around a `<textarea>` and appending it to the page i'm viewing. But unfortunatly this page im reading has two div's which im grabbing content form and only in one div tinymce is loadding. please help me solve this. help much appreciated.
my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = "ex/ex2/file.html";
    $.get(page, function (response) {
         //following functions initializes tinymce                          
            tinymce_init();
        $(response).find('.lookingclassname').each(function () {

            var clscontent = $(this).html();
            var cls = $(this).attr('class').toString();
            var clsarr = cls.split(" ");

            $.post("index.php?component=static_content&action=check_contnet&classname="+clsarr[clsarr.length-1],       function(data) {
              if($(data).find(".error").length){
            var topcover = '<textarea name="editlive' + clsarr[clsarr.length - 1] + '" id="editlive' + clsarr[clsarr.length - 1] + '" rows="10" cols="90">';
            var bottomcover = '</textarea><input type="submit" name="btnsavecontent" value="SAVE" onClick="saveContent(' + clsarr[clsarr.length - 1] + ')" id="btnsavecontent" />';
            $('.bodyContent').append(topcover + clscontent + bottomcover);
            }
           });

        });
    });

});
```

no matter where i put tinymce_init(); its not working...

Comment: Have you tried putting the `tinymce_init();` after the `each` ?

Comment: ah yeah i works ! hehe. how did that happen.. :/ u have an explanation ?

Comment: it stop working again... can you please check the question i edit?

Comment: ok worked again . i moved tinymce_init(); after if condition. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `init` only once. Causing it multiple times (within the each where it was) is known to cause strange behaviour. Putting it after adding your new content is the most logical place.